# Saving bookmarks in a database using javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bookmarks

I want to save a bookmark permanently in a database using javascript. I have an idea.

"I have a service. so that i shall use that service to interact my code and the database."

I am struck with this how to begin. I would like you to suggest whether this is possible. If so how to proceed with this?

Comment: Things you need to specify.  Do you have a separate website and database set up?  Something like an ASP.Net site, PHP site, etc, and the associated database like MS SQL Server, MySQL, etc?  If no, you would need to set that up.  Then it is a matter of generating AJAX requests from your JavaScript code to the website that interacts with the database and interpreting the response.  It can be done.  We use databases to skin and customize template websites (including OpenLayers and soon ESRI web maps).  We need to know your server set up and your experience coding these things.